# Add a TEXT element in SQLite with space

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

i'm new using SQLite so probably it's a simple problem to solve, but I couldn't find a working solution on the internet. I have a SQLite Database with a single table, when I try to add a new element to the table I cannot insert spaces within words.

```
public void addThingToDb(int id, string user, string description)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO Assets(id, user, description) VALUES({id}, {user}, {description})";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

When i run it i get:
SQL logic error near " were": syntax error

if for example `description="I were";`

i tried also to add single quote and double quote (whit the help of the backslash ) but i get an other error, because SQL think that the word after the quote is a new column (like an SQL Injection attack). Please help me

Comment: Please try wrapping the strings with single quote ' i.e: '{description}', also it will be highly encouraging if you will use Prepared Statement to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameters, do not insert strings inside other strings when you build an sql statement. For example what do you think will happen if one of your strings contains a single quote? And this is the least important of your problems. Sql Injection is the big problem here.

```
public void addThingToDb(int id, string user, string description)
{
    cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO Assets(id, user, description) VALUES(@id, @user, @description)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@int", DbType.Int32).Value = id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", DbType.String).Value = user;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", DbType.String).Value = description;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

To explain your actual problem instead. A string value should be enclosed between single quotes to be recognized as such. The actual code fails because the space breaks the syntax of your stringized query. Again use parameters and this problem goes away

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the explanation and the solution. Really helpful!!!